# Finding a vector space over $F$ of dimension $m$ and $n$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

The question is below:

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over $F$ of dimensions $m$ and $n$, respectively. Find a basis for $L(V,W)$.

This is what I have:

Let$ (v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_m)$ be a basis of $V$ and $(w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_n)$ a basis of $W$. Then for each pair of $(i,j)$, let $A(i,j)$ be the linear transformation $(V,W)$ such that $A_{ij}V_j = W_i$ and $A_{ij}V_k=0$ if $k$ is not equal to $J$. Then the $mn$ linear transformations of $\{ A_{ij} \}$ form a basis for $L(V,W)$.

My question is:

How to show mn linear transformation from the bases that I stated above?

Comment: Can you show that your transformations are linearly independent (what does a linear combination do to each $V_i$)?. Can you show that any linear transformation is a linear combination of these (think about matrices)?

Comment: thanks for the comment! i will try show those.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is very good. More precisely, define
$$
A_{ij}\colon V\to W
$$
as the unique linear map such that
$$
A_{ij}(v_k)=\begin{cases}
w_j & \text{if $i=k$}\\[4px]
0   & \text{if $i\ne k$}
\end{cases}
$$
Note that these linear maps are well defined because $\{v_1,\dots,v_m\}$ is a basis of $V$.

Let's show that this set of linear maps is linearly independent. Suppose
$$
\sum_{i,j}\alpha_{ij}A_{ij}=0
$$
(the zero map). If we evaluate it at $v_k$, we get
$$
0=\sum_{i,j}\alpha_{ij}A_{ij}(v_k)=
\sum_{j}\sum_{i}\alpha_{ij}A_{ij}(v_k)=
\sum_{j}\alpha_{kj}w_j
$$
and, by the linear independence of $\{w_1,\dots,w_n\}$ we deduce $\alpha_{kj}=0$. Since $1\le k\le m$ is arbitrary, we reach our goal.

Now we need to show that any $A\colon V\to W$ is a linear combination of the given maps. For $1\le i\le m$, we have
$$
A(v_i)=\sum_{j}\alpha_{ij}w_j
$$
for uniquely determined scalars $\alpha_{ij}$, because $\{w_1,\dots,w_n\}$ is a basis of $W$ and it's natural to consider
$$
\sum_{i,j}\alpha_{ij}A_{ij}
$$
as the candidate for being equal to $A$. Let $1\le k\le m$; then
$$
\sum_{i,j}\alpha_{ij}A_{ij}(v_k)=
\sum_{j}\sum_{i}\alpha_{ij}A_{ij}(v_k)=
\sum_{j}\alpha_{kj}w_j=
A(v_k)
$$
by definition. Since $A$ and the candidate agree on the elements of a basis, they are equal.